# Extract subtring after certain text and before hyphen (regex)

Tags: python, regex, extract

I have a list of emails that match a similar pattern as such:

chris-repo-nonprod-red-sens@mail.com

ryan-prod-blue-sens@mail.com

The first email has 5 parts while the second one has 4 parts (marked by the hyphen) before the @mail.com

I need to extract the group_code that comes after the nonprod/prod portion of the group email.

For example for chris-repo-nonprod-red-sens@mail.com i need to extract red,

and for ryan-prod-blue-sens@mail.com i need to extract blue.

The portion before the group code will always be prod or nonprod, further more there will always be the subtring "prod-" before the group code.

How can I go about extracting the group code from emails that have different amount of parts to always get the group code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
re.findall('(?:prod-)(.*)-', s)
```

```
df['group'] = df['col2'].str.extract('(?:prod-)(.*)-' )
df
```

```
    col1    col2                                    group
0   1       chris-repo-nonprod-red-sens@mail.com    red
1   2       ryan-prod-blue-sens@mail.com            blue
2   3                                               NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [rfind & find](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rfind.html)

```
email2 = 'ryan-nonprod-blue-sens@mail.com'
email = 'chris-repo-nonprod-red-sens@mail.com'

start = 'prod-'
start2= 'nonprod-'
end = '-'

print( (email[email.find(start or start2)+len(start or start2):email.rfind(end)]))
print("\n")
```

output

```
red
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be working

```
(?<=prod-)[a-z]+
```

Based on the input data that we have

```
chris-repo-nonprod-red-sens@mail.com
ryan-prod-blue-sens@mail.com
```

and on the note that we always have **nonprod** or **prod** upfront the searching string, we can utilize regexp assertion. In this case positive look-behind assertion **(?<=prod-)** where we define that we are looking for **prod-** just before any word **[a-z]+**

Note: assertion is not a part of the result

Comment: a little bit more code and some explanations would have been helpful.